# No values being passed to View Model in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a small asp project for user requests. I'm very new to ASP.NET. I've just created a new view model that looks like this.

```
public class createViewModel
{
    public Change Changevm = new Change();

    public List<RequestType> rTypes = new List<RequestType>();
}
```

Easy Peasy. Now in my controller my POST actionresult looks like this.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(createViewModel _newViewModel)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here 
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (UserRequestContextDataContext db = new UserRequestContextDataContext())
                {

                    Request crObj = new Request();
                    crObj.Title = _createViewModel.Changevm.Title.ToString();
                    crObj.Description = _createViewModel.Changevm.Description.ToString();

                    db.Requests.InsertOnSubmit(crObj);
                    db.SubmitChanges();
                }   
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

            return View("Error", new HandleErrorInfo(ex,"Change","Create"));
        }
    }
```

So the problem is when executing there is no data being passed from the form to the view model. I'm sure its just my noobishness. When I step through, every field is just null. I don't really understand where to bind to the view model. If i'm completely doing this wrong feel free to suggest.

Any help, or direction to appropriate materials is great.

<< UPDATE >>
Here is my view, sorry about that.

```
@model UserRequests.ViewModels.createViewModel

@{

ViewBag.Title = "Create Change";


List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
for (int x = 1; x < 6; x++)
{
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = x.ToString(),
        Value = x.ToString()
    });
}


List<SelectListItem> listTypes = new List<SelectListItem>();

foreach(var item in Model.rTypes)
{
    listTypes.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = item.Name.ToString(),
        Value = item.Id.ToString()
    });
}

}
<h2>Create a Request</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Fill out this form as completely as possible.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Changevm.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Changevm.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Changevm.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Changevm.Type, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Changevm.Type, listTypes ,"-- Choose One -- ", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "" } })

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Changevm.Type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Changevm.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Changevm.Description, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = 5, @id = "editor1" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Changevm.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Changevm.SubmitDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Changevm.SubmitDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Changevm.SubmitDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Changevm.BusinessUnit, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Changevm.BusinessUnit, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(x => x.Changevm.BusinessUnit, ViewData).Watermark } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Changevm.BusinessUnit, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Changevm.ModuleName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Changevm.ModuleName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(x => x.Changevm.ModuleName, ViewData).Watermark, @style = "color:black"} })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Changevm.ModuleName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Changevm.UrgencyNum, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Changevm.UrgencyNum, listItems, "-- Urgency Level (1 = Least Urgent) -- ", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Changevm.UrgencyNum, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-5">
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to Home", "Index", "Home")
</div>
```

Comment: What does the `View` look like? The `.cshtml` portion.

Comment: You need to bind the model in the view. We need to see the view code to see what is going on there.

Comment: are you specifing the model in your View? as `@model Test.Models.createViewModel`

Comment: Sorry about that, added the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing viewmodel properties to use getters and setters, not sure if this is the issue but I have never seen viewmodel properties handled that way.

```
public class createViewModel
{
    public Change Changevm { get; set; }

    public List<RequestType> rTypes { get; set; }
}
```

As the comments stated you should also post your view as there could be some things going on there as well.